# How to select a value from a table separated by a comma in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
ID           tags
--------------------------------
1             1,2,3,4
2             2,3,4
3             4,22
4             2
```

this is my MySQL query

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tags LIKE '%2%'"
```

when I write above query to search only '2' in tags column it will give me '22' as a result. So how do I prevent get '22' when I search only '2'. I need to get result as

```
ID           tags
--------------------------------
1             1,2,3,4
2             2,3,4
4             2
```

Comment: You have some fundamental problems with your database if you're storing multiple values in a single cell.

Comment: You need to normalize your table. A row for each value. There are ways to get it to work but it is best to just normalize now before it is way more work..

Comment: The above query will also give you results with tags as 12,32 and so on if such tags are present in the table.

Moreover your database structure should be changed. You need to normalize your table. 

Use one to many relation where you can save tags in another table with ID as its foreign key

Comment: like %2% will give you anything2anything

Comment: use this `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tags REGEXP '^.%2%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this MySQL query,

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, tags)"
```

It will help you